# silverware validator doesn't work on CMS frontend of silverstripe

Tags: php, validation, content-management-system, silverstripe

Does anyone know how to setup one silverstripe's module named silverware/validator to work on cms frontend?

We just found there is on issue about the cms jquery version is too old to use this module, it needs at least > jquery1.8.*, bur right know the cms only uses 1.7.2.

We have spent couple of days to fix it, but we can't find any way to import new jquery version instead of old one on CMS.

We check it out from silverstripe blogs, it seems there is no way so far to fix it.

REF for module:https://github.com/praxisnetau/silverware-validator
REF from silverstripe: https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/issues/3384

Any ideas for this?